# C#, how to call a form object from a tray based application

Tags: c#, winforms, systray

I am trying to load a form class from a program running as a tray icon that originally used

```
FileList frmFileList = new FileList();
```

Now instead of a filelist I want to use a custom form but I get the error:

> Error 1
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the "Cast"? What did you try to do? Post some code.

Comment: Please show us the line that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forgot `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source file.  But since you didn't post the sources, I can't say for sure.  Posting the line of code that causes the error message, and the `using` directives that are in that same file would help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not trying something like this?

```
FileList frmFileList = new SomethingDifferent();
```

If so, change the FileList on the left side to SomethingDifferent.

Comment: FileList frmFileList = new FileList(); IT WAS and now I tried DOScharForm Dform = new DOScharForm();
So what's the diff?

Comment: @user559057: It's not a message board or forum.  It's a Q&A site.

Comment: Yes  cdhowie but the difference makes it hard to make sense of my questions. I am having trouble in Csharp with enacting a form from a program that appears to require a comand line text rendering basis? The calsls are:

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to instantiate a form object in a console application? That doesn't make any sense

Comment: The Error System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' could be found...from:  foreach (var child in c.Controls.Cast<Control>()) { DisableCompatibleTextRendering(child); } } I think my problem stems from trying to utilise/adapt VB code in a Csharp program?
The line generating the error=
foreach (var child in c.Controls.Cast<Control>()){ DisableCompatibleTextRendering(child);}} 
?[var child]?+no cast is known for that call in Csharp?

Comment: !!!AHA!!! Shift enter for a new line! lol
My apologies for my 'newbie' approach and thanks for your guys' attention.