# Csharp, how to call a form object from a tray based application

Tags: c#, winforms, systray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, how to call a form object from a tray based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568815/c-how-to-call-a-form-object-from-a-tray-based-application)

Hi guys,

Iam trying to load a form class from a program running as a tray icon that originally used 
"FileList frmFileList = new FileList();"  Now instead of a filelist I want to use a custom form but I get the error:
Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Any ideas?

Comment: Dupe of poster's earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568815/c-how-to-call-a-form-object-from-a-tray-based-application. Please don't repost questions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you forgot `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source file.  But since you didn't post the sources, I can't say for sure.  Posting the line of code that causes the error message, and the `using` directives that are in that same file would help.

Comment: OMG cdhowie FANTASTIC! However it now brings up the problem of: SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application. So do you or any other brilliant mind know how to get round this please? Can I swap the IWin32Window object or...*blush*... Where even would this have been ceated? Cheers dude. lol

Comment: Where are you calling `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault`?  Can this be moved to your `Main` method so it only gets called once, before any window objects are created?